# Value Objects Vs Entities

Tags: domain-driven-design, entities, value-objects

Quick question... When approaching something like an email address the immediate idea is to treat this as a value object.

If we have a number of entities though, say a customer, a contact, and a supplier that are referencing the same email address, it is conceivable that when we change a customer's email address we may want the customer's contact, and they may be a supplier too, have that email change reflected with those entities as well. Am I correct in thinking this is giving the email address identity so it should now be represented as an entity?

Cheers,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe you're on the right lines.  See my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679005/how-are-value-objects-stored-in-the-database/681106#681106).